# Ajax php call returning data to body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a php file from ajax and having trouble getting the response inside the set div #content. Everything echoed flies straight to the start of the body. I am not getting any sort of error status from ajax either. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the php file:

```
if($_GET["id"]) {
    $aPoem = $poems->find(array('language'=>($_GET["id"])));
    foreach($aPoem as $poem) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?id=' . $poem["_id"] . '" target="_self">' . $poem["title"] .'</a><br>';
    }
}
```

Ajax file:

```
function sendLanguage() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "./ListTranslations.php",
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response){
    $('#content').html(response);
    }).fail(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    });
```

}

Any help much appreciated!

Edited a typo.

Comment: At done function r should be response right?

Comment: error in r and response

Comment: `if($_GET["id"]) {` wouldn't that always be false for this ajax request?

Comment: I have id set in the url and the db calls are working correctly for each $_GET["id"] im calling. If it returns a false then it shouldn't even get inside the if at all?

Answer (score -1):

Try innerHTML: 
`$('#content').innerHTML += response;`

Comment: yeah, no. don't try that.